# Changing Element Position Using an IF

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, redirect, timer

At the moment I'm creating a Plugin for a Redirect Timer.

I'm trying to make the Position var for the button that looks like :

`Button_Position` and I want to be able to do: Left, Center, Right

For example:

```
Button_Position = "center"
```

Which should center the button

This my code im using to attempt this:

```
document.write("<div class='holder'></div>");  

if(typeof Button_Position=="left"){
$('.holder').html("<div id='style'></div><span id='redirect'></span><center><button id='buttonn' style='cursor:pointer;float:left;'>"+Button_Value+" &gt;&gt;</button></center>");
}
if(typeof Button_Position=="center"){
$('.holder').html("<div id='style'></div><span id='redirect'></span><center><button id='buttonn' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+Button_Value+" &gt;&gt;</button></center>");
}
if(typeof Button_Position=="right"){
$('.holder').html("<div id='style'></div><span id='redirect'></span><center><button id='buttonn' style='cursor:pointer;float:right;'>"+Button_Value+" &gt;&gt;</button></center>");
}
```

The Problem is that the Button is not showing anymore like it used to.
Hope someone can help
**NOTE: The var for Button_Position is in my Plugin code so that's not the problem.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove that "typeof"

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/hXtVW/7/

```
Button_Position = "left";
Button_Value = "hi";
if(Button_Position=="left"){
$('.holder').html("<div id='style'></div><span id='redirect'></span><center><button id='buttonn' style='cursor:pointer;float:left;'>"+Button_Value+" &gt;&gt;</button></center>");
}
if(Button_Position=="center"){
$('.holder').html("<div id='style'></div><span id='redirect'></span><center><button id='buttonn' style='cursor:pointer;'>"+Button_Value+" &gt;&gt;</button></center>");
}
if(Button_Position=="right"){
$('.holder').html("<div id='style'></div><span id='redirect'></span><center><button id='buttonn' style='cursor:pointer;float:right;'>"+Button_Value+" &gt;&gt;</button></center>");
}
```

shows hi >>

Comment: But it should be refactored to eliminate all that identical stuff.

Comment: @Shawn31313: no, ignore Dave, he was just trying to make it more clear